# How to target only tablet devices in a cordova Android app

Tags: android, css, cordova, media-queries

I have a requirement for an Android App to be built with Cordova (a hybrid App) HTML5 and CSS, and this app needs to target all (only) tablet devices starting from 7" to the largest (I believe it's 10.1"). Could someone advice on a standard implementation on media queries setup for this requirement? 
I am confused with the resolution and the DPI concepts of Android, when building a hybrid app with above requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Use this configuration in Manifest to allow only Tablet devices.

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: this definitely helped. Thanks Imran! :)
I also need the Media query implementation, and I got that too :)

Comment: This is the official documentation reference https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps

Comment: I don't have manifest xml until i do a build. Is it possible this supports-screens to be set somehow in config.xml? Also if i update manifest file manually and run new cordova build, it will be override.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for media queries to target you app resolution to Tablets only, here is your [solution](http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/)

Comment: thanks Murtaza... what is with the DPI (ldpi, mdpi, etc.)? do I have to handle them too? and how do I do that?

Comment: okay.. I'm starting on the implementation with the link that you gave and adding th e <support-screens> in manifest as well.
Thanks again :)

Comment: Murtaza Khursheed Hussain: I have two devices now - Samsung Tab 4 and Samsung Note- both are 10.1 Inches and both are 1280X800. The problem is, in the Note, the navigation panel of the device is inside the screen. And thus, the height has an issue of about ~20px. Please could you let me know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Media queries have been used in RWD(responsive web design) to response to different size or breakpoints in HTML by using CSS media query tag.

If you were targeting to single break-point or sets of small screen size then you don't need to have media queries in your CSS. Or you also can use any existing framework that optimized for mobile phone screen size like Ionic or Framework 7.