# How to handle Android devices with same resolution but with different screen heights

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, media-queries

This is an extension to my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742319/how-to-target-only-tablet-devices-in-a-cordova-android-app).
I have two devices now - Samsung Tab 4 and Samsung Note - both are 10.1 Inches and both are 1280X800 resolution. The problem is, in the Note device, the navigation panel (Back button, Home button) of the device is inside the screen. And thus, the height is decreased by ~48px. The app's content doesn't appear up to the extent of the navigation panel. Please could you let me know how to handle this? I am looking for a solution that satisfies similar condition on 7" tablet devices too. (e.g. Samsung 7" tab has its navigation panel on the device body whereas nexus 7 device has its navigation panel within the device inside the screen).

I tried `height=device-height` in the `<meta>` tag but did not work.

Comment: You can always use layouts with no hard coded sizes so it will adapt to all screen sizes painlessly.

Comment: @linus: should I use % instead of em/px?

Comment: yeah, something like that. If you are building some simple UI first, i suggest you can try and stick with linearlayouts.

Comment: any other work around? using screenHeight etc.? Width is not a problem for me... am facing issues with the Height...

Comment: you can use @media queries

Comment: @Amar1989: can you give me a working example please...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the @media queries. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: lightblue;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
                body {
                    background-color: lightgreen;
                }
            }
        </style>
     </head>
    <body>
     ...
</body>
</html>
```

This will change the background color of the body to lightblue. But when you resize your browser window to less than 300px it will change to lightgreen. I hope this will help you with your problem.